# Make background of TextArea opaque

Tags: java, swingbuilder, swing-app-framework

I want to make my TextArea's background opaque. I'm using swing gui forms at netbeans.

I want to overlap the instructions infront of the image ([see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDr5x.jpg)), but the problem is texts can't be seen if they are infront of the image. I really don't know if the not opaque background is the problem here (I've use the layered pane to have a JLabel where the picture was located and overlapping the TextArea where i placed my instructions).

Can you help me figure out what the problem is? 
[image]

here's the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class About extends javax.swing.JDialog {

public About(JFrame owner) {
    super(owner, true);
    initComponents();
    setSize(500, 500);
    setLocation(300, 120);
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(204, 204, 255));
    jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("HangmanStartlight.jpg"));

 }

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jLayeredPane1 = new javax.swing.JLayeredPane();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");
    jLabel1.setBounds(0, 0, 420, 290);
    jLayeredPane1.add(jLabel1, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jTextArea1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 51));
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jTextArea1.setText("Hangman\n\nGuess the \"HIDDEN PHRASE\" to proceed to the next\nlevel.  Hangman is filled with several words, \npresented in random order each time you play.\n\nhOw To pLay!!!\n\nYou can select letters by clicking on the letter buttons\nshown at the window.\n\nBe very careful! 'coz you are only allowed 10 wrong\nguesses per puzzle.\n\nYou will at the corner Top-Left of the window your \n\"Name\", your \"Score\", your \"Level\", your \"Lives Left\"\nand also the \"Life Line\" which you can use as a Hint.\n\nEnjoy Playing and Have Fun :)");
    jTextArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

    jScrollPane1.setBounds(0, 0, 420, 280);
    jLayeredPane1.add(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    jTabbedPane1.addTab("tab1", jLayeredPane1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(26, 26, 26)
            .addComponent(jTabbedPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 427, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(39, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(21, 21, 21)
            .addComponent(jTabbedPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 313, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(128, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLayeredPane jLayeredPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

p.s. i am using swing builder/ swing gui forms..

Comment: It would probably help if you were to share some code and show us what you've tried so far. Also, in the picture in your question, the background of the text **is** opaque. Do you mean that you want it to be transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using one of the tips from [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/).

Answer (score -1):

Write your own component which draws the text manually on the screen. That's how game's are made in Java, not with Swing...